# Check if Object1's keys are in Object2 if so compare values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How would I go about doing the following. I need to see if my object1.keys are in object2, if the key is there I need to compare the value, if the values are different I need to replace Object2's value with Object1's value.

Object1:

```
object1 = {
   firstName: "Bob",
   lastName: "Smith",
   dob: "May 25, 1977"
}
```

Object2:

```
object2 = {
   firstName: "Bobby",
   lastName: "Jones",
   dob: "May 25, 1977",
   created: "May 24, 1977",
   userLevel: "jedi"
}
```

Desired output for Object2:

```
object2 = {
   firstName: "Bob",
   lastName: "Smith",
   dob: "May 25, 1977",
   created: "May 24, 1977",
   userLevel: "jedi"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the desired output as well?

Comment: I have tried a few different things but none have worked. I figured I wouldn't add random code that didn't work :/

Comment: When i read "if the key is there, [...]", i assume keys that are not already present should not be copied, is that correct? E.g. `object1 = { a: 0 }; object2 = {}`, is the desired result that `object2` is still `{}`? I ask this mostly because some answers copy keys either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use for in on first object and compare

```js
let object1 = {
   firstName: "Bob",
   lastName: "Smith",
   dob: "May 25, 1977"
}

let object2 = {
   firstName: "Bobby",
   lastName: "Jones",
   dob: "May 25, 1977",
   created: "May 24, 1977",
   userLevel: "jedi"
}

for(let key in object1){
  if(object2[key]){
    object2[key] = object1[key]
  }
}

console.log(object2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Object.assign(object2, object1);
```

or to not mutate `object2` but creating a new object:

```
 const newObj = {...object2, ...object1}
```

That assigns all values from object1 to object2. If they are the same, it doesnt matter if we copy them.